# render = font.render(text, 1, (0, 0, 0)) pygame.error: Library not initialized

Tags: python

the error im receiving is : file "/home/lucas/python/cargame/utils.py", line 17, in blit_text_center
render = font.render(text, 1, (0, 0, 0))
pygame.error: Library not initialized

the problem which seems to be somewhere in this piece of code:
def blit_text_center(win, font, text):
render = font.render(text, 1, (0, 0, 0))
win.blit(render, (win.get_width()/2 - render.get_width() /
2, win.get_height()/2 - render.get_height()/2)) - this code is not the main.py code.

The problem could also have something to do with this piece of code: from utils import scale_image, blit_rotate_center, blit_text_center
pygame.font.init()

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! It might be a surprise to you that your question is off-topic. This site focuses on the theory behind programming, not on programming using a particular language or software. Please see our [help on topic](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Your question might be on-topic on [SO].

Comment: A simple request to debug incorrect code is not welcomed everywhere in general. You should create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with clear description of the problem. Then your post might fit [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).